# Can we use pyspark in the backend to build the models and then use Rshiny in frontend to build an interactive dashboard?

Tags: shiny, pyspark, sparkr

I am trying to use SparkR now to build the backend where I have a random forest model running. But I need decision tree and sparkR does not have that. Also, sparkR lacks proper documentation . Also, I dont know if there is something as easy as Rshiny in Python. So I want to know if it is possible to build an application with Pyspark and ShinyR.

Answer (score 0):

For a quickly working web app I found that shiny was pretty useful. I called `.py` scripts from the R server and it worked well, but it was a bit slow since it has to start up a session and allocate resources.

I found the best work around was to use spark streaming instead. It checked if new files had been written by shiny into a directory, reads them, processes them and writes output results (you can lag the R server so that it has time to write the output before reading them into R).

For easy to use python based frameworks, you can check out `python-dash`.